# Which armature with face bones and/or which addon can I use to make the mocap?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, motion-capture

I tried to use the makewalk and the Motion Capture Addon by Benjy Cook with different armatures : mine armature,with remapped bones and without ; with the rigify + pitchipoi addon,before to get the final rig and after. It did never work. The Benjy Cook addon does not include the option for the remapping of the face bones,the makewalk addon used in combination with the rigify + pitchipoi gives always the same error :

> Found no candidate hip bone / hip bone must have children hips.

So,I haven't found a good way to make the mocap if I want to retarget also the face bones. Also,the makehuman pre made armature with the mocap / Cmu mb version has no face bones,so it's not useful at all for me. I tried to remap the bones using my armature,but it didn't work at the same way. I need to find another addon. Do you know another one ? I don't want to use the markers approach and/or the shapekeys,but I want to use the bones and a pre made armature that includes the face bones. Thanks.